# Google Annotation chart decimals length

Tags: javascript, charts, annotations, google-visualization

I'd like to solve my google annotation chart problem.

I use chart to show numbers. I'd like this format: 987654.**654321**

[mychart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqchO.png)

But the chart legend container show only 2 decimal numbers like 987654.**65**, but i have to show the whole length of the numbers.

I searched some tips on google and i found something about [formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts). But in the end i could not solved.

have anybody's solution for this problem?

Here is my code:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['annotationchart', 'controls']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  $.get("testfile.csv", function(csvString) {
    // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {
      onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar
    });

    for (var i = 1; i < arrayData.length; i++)
      arrayData[i][0] = new Date(arrayData[i][0]); // converting strings to Dates

    // this new DataTable object holds all the data
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

    // CAPACITY - En-route ATFM delay - YY - CHART
    var crt_ertdlyYY = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'AnnotationChart',
      containerId: 'annchart',
      dataTable: data,
      options: {
        displayAnnotations: true,
        colors: ['#c16032'],
        width: 750,
        height: 400
      }
    });
    crt_ertdlyYY.draw();
  });
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

```html
<div id="annchart"></div>
```

Comment: do you mean comma or decimal?

Comment: Dear @kemotoe, i mean decimal.